# Avoiding storing duplicate strings in ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Suppose I have the following models:

```
    class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :tips
    end

    class Tip < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
```

A tip description is just a `VARCHAR(140)` in a MySQL database, and most of them are canned values, such as "Wear a raincoat" or "Bring a checkbook". I would like to use normalization to avoid storing a large number of strings with the same value, however, if I add `belongs_to :event` to the `Tip` model, the `event_id` value will lead to many duplicate tips.

How can I get the benefits of normalization without manually managing the `tip_id <---> tip_description` mapping?

Comment: How will `belongs_to` lead to duplicate?? Can you brief??

Comment: If two events A and B each have a tip whose description is "Bring an umbrella", then there will be two entries in the `tips` table, since A.id != B.id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid repeated entries in table then use `has_and_belongs_to_many`

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tips
end

class Tip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

Migration to create `events_tips`:

```
class CreateEventsTips < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events_tips, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :event_id
      t.integer :tip_id
    end
  end
end
```

In controller:

```
tip = Tip.find_or_create_by_tip_description(params[:tip][:description])
Event.find_by_id(params[:id]).tips << tip
```